# Which way should I use to remove duplicates from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to remove any duplicates

```
list2 = [element for element in list1 if element not in list2]
```

however,

```
    for i in list1:
        if i not in list2:
            list2.append(i)
```

this code works perfectly fine, can anyone please let me know why is this the case?

Comment: ```list2 = [element for element in list1 if element not in list2]``` because ```list2``` is not properly defined. You are creating a list named ```list2``` and in the list comprehension, checking if the elements are there in ```list2```

Comment: @Xitiz Telling why it doesn't work

Comment: @Sujay probably not refreshed in mine :)

Comment: I use `newlist = list(set(list1))` where `list1` has duplicates and `newlist` is a list which does not have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It's producing an identical list as list2 contains no elements at run-time. What you'd want is this:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2, 8, 5, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 5, 8]
list2 = []
[list2.append(item) for item in list1 if item not in list2]
print(list2)
```

Comment: You're needlessly creating a list of `[None, None, None]` here...